# Why do ultraproduct structures use a quotient as their universe?

Tags: model-theory, filters

For an $L$-structure $\mathfrak{A}$ with universe $A$, if we have an index set $I$, with an ultrafilter $U$, we create an ultraproduct structure having as its universe $\Pi_I \;A_i/U$. This is the set of equivalence classes of $\Pi_I A_i$ modulo ~, where $a$ ~ $b$ iff $\{i \;|\; a(i) = b(i) \} \in U$. Why do we need, or why is it better to use the quotient, rather than just $\Pi_IA_i$ as the universe? It seems we could still define a model having this product as the universe -  relations would still be those elements where the relation in $\mathfrak{A}$ holds over the ultrafilter, and functions and constants would also be defined as they are normally for ultraproducts. So why the need (or desire) to work with equivalence classes? They seem to just make things more confusing.

Comment: Perhaps it's "more confusing" when you first see it, but iIt would be much more confusing, and ultimately much more work, to just use the product. That would require entire parallel redefinitions of first order equality, first order satisfaction, and so on — first order logic modulo an equivalence relation.

Comment: Why? When defining those things with equivalence classes (FO equality, satisfaction, etc.), we just use a representative for the definitions anyway. I don't see where the equivalence class structure comes into play at all.

Comment: For one thing, equality would not actually be equality, just *$R$-equivalence*.

Comment: Sorry, what's $R$-equivalence? And why is that a problem?

Comment: As I said, in effect you'd have to develop parallel definitions of equality mod some equivalence relation $R$, satisfaction mod $R$, and so on. In the case of ultraproducts, $R$ would be the usual relation $xRy \iff \{i\mid x_i = y_i\}\in U$, but why limit things to the special case of ultrafilter eq. rel.s? So $=$ would end up being interpreted as $R$-equivalence, not identity. Similarly, the definition of satisfaction gets mucked up. All this needless reduplication of work is to save *you* from the confusion you experience on first meeting the definition of ultraproducts.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think there's something fundamental I'm misunderstanding. Why would you need to develop equality, satisfaction, etc. mod an equivalence relation? What's wrong with equivalence just being identity? And having a formula be satisfied iff it is satisfied over some set in the ultrafilter? Why do the *elements* of the universe of our model need to be equivalence classes? I'm just having trouble coming to grips with this. Thank you very much for taking the time to respond!

Comment: If the universe were simply the product, and we used the usual definitions of satisfaction in a model, then identity would not "identify" elements that are equivalent mod-$U$, and there would be no mention of the mod-$U$ relation. Without special-case definitions, satisfaction and truth in the ultraproduct are just satisfaction and truth in the product. How would we get the fundamental result that a sentence $S$ is true in the ultraproduct *iff*  $\{i\in I\mid A_i\models S\} \in U$ ?

Comment: The most basic answer to this question is "Because we want Łoś's theorem to be true."

Comment: Your confusion is a temporary thing. You'll get used to quotients and never ever think about them again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the *most* part, model theorists are concerned with complete theories. This means, for a fixed language $\mathcal{L}$, an $\mathcal{L}-$theory $T$ is complete if for every $\varphi$ in this language, $T \vdash \varphi$ or $T \vdash \neg \varphi$. Now, there are exceptions to this rule. Sometimes you care about model companions, or quantifier elimination for a collection of theories (e.g. **ACF**), but again, for the most part, many model theorists care about complete theories.

**Question 0:** Why ultrapowers and not Cartesian products?

By the argument above, we care about the class (or category) of models of a complete theory $T$ (where our morphisms are elementary embeddings). Notice that if $T =$ $\mathbf{AFC_0}$, then $\mathbb{C} \models T$. However, $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C} \not \models T$ since $(0,1)$ does not have a multiplicative inverse. Actually, it is somewhat rare for cartesian products of models (with pointwise interpretations) to be models of our original theory.

On the other hand, ultrapowers/ultraproducts fixes our problem. By Łoś's Theorem, $\{i:A_i\models\varphi(a_{i_1},...,a_{i_n})\}\in D$ iff $\prod_D A_i \models \varphi([a_1],...,[a_n])$. Furthermore, if $A_i \equiv A_j$ for each $i,j \in I$, we can conclude that $A_i \equiv \prod_DA_i$. In English, a first order sentence is true in the ultraproduct iff it is true in over a "large" subcollection of our models and if each $A_i$ is a model of $T$, then $\prod_D A_i$ is also a model of $T$.

**Remark:** In the category theory interpretation, if $A_i \in \mathcal{C}(T)$, then $\prod_DA_i \in \mathcal{C}(T)$. Furthermore, there is a natural elementary embedding from a model $A_i$ to an ultrapower $\prod_DA_i$ via the diagonal embedding (i.e. $d(a)=[a]$).

**Question 1:** How do we generate new models of a complete theory $T$ from old models of $T$?

The quick and fast answer is compactness and the upward and downward Löwenheim–Skolem theorems. However, these theorems just tell us "there is some model of cardinality $\kappa$ that realizes this collection of types". With more work, you can prove the omitting-types theorem which allows you to conclude "there is some model of cardinality $\kappa$ that omits this (small) collection of non-principal types".

On the other hand, ultraproducts and ultrapowers give you more control over saturation, realizing types, and actually elements. For instance, Let $A= (\mathbb{N};<)$ and let $|I|=\aleph_0$. Then, consider $\prod_DA_i$. In this case, I can actually give you an infinite descending chain in this structure (i.e. $(1,2,3,4,...),(0,1,2,3,...),(0,0,1,2,...)$).

**Question 2:** How exactly does this differ from controlled compactness?

Here is where I place my plug for the Keisler order. Classical "classification theory" deals with how one finds dividing lines among the collection of all complete theories. Why is arithmetic over the natural numbers so much harder than arithmetic over the reals? What do linear orders and the random graph have in common? The Keisler order is a lens in which we can under stand "how hard" it is to saturate all types over a model of a (countable) complete theory. This (pre-)order determines how "hard" this process is by considering "how strong" of an ultrafilter is necessary to achieve $\kappa-$saturation. Therefore, ultraproducts are also useful in finding dividing lines between first-order theories.

Comment: What justification do you have for your claim that for the most part model theorists are concerned with complete theories?

Comment: @RobArthan: So, for instance, the notion of morphism in the category of models of a theory T is an elementary embedding. If T is incomplete, consider $T_1$ and $T_2$ as two separate completions. Then, there are no morphism between any of the objects in the category of models of $T_1$ into the category of models of $T_2$ (and vice versa). I'm on mobile right now, but will upload more sources when I get to a computer.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write up this explanation. I wasn't aware that, in general, cartesian products of models are not themselves models of the original theory. I feel this answers my question, so I've accepted your answer. As a follow up, would you happen to know historically how people realized that ultrafilters were required in order to correctly "stitch together" models?